# print an arraylist while passing it from a controller to a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

hi i am trying to print the contents of an arraylist in a jsp 
 here is the controller code

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteFilter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteFilter(FilterValues filterData,ModelMap modalMap) {

    logger.info("delete a filter");
    ArrayList<String> filtername= mongoService.getTargetFiltersName();
    modalMap.addAttribute("filterslist",  filtername);

    return "delete";
}
```

and here is the part of the jsp where i have to print it

```
 <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="pwd">Filter Name:</label>
                         <select type="Filter Name" class="form-control" id="pwd"     placeholder="Enter Filter Name">
                         <c:forEach items="${filterslist}" var="filtername">
                                 <option value="${filtername.value}">${filtername.value}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </select>                   
                        </div>
```

its giving me errors

thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe, what errors?

Comment: @edward what error..??

Comment: please post the stacktrace

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'value'.

Comment: hey guys i just typed filtername instead of filtername.value and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use the following code as you are iterating on an `ArrayList` of `String`

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<label for="pwd">Filter Name:</label>
 <select type="Filter Name" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Filter Name">
 <c:forEach items="${filterslist}" var="filtername">
         <option value="${filtername}">${filtername}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>                  
</div>
```